# TypeError: Cannot read property 'setState' of undefined onGridRowsUpdated (adazzle React Data Grid )

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-data-grid

I'm using adazzle's React-Data-Grid to display a table data of users from a REST backend service. The grid is displaying the users data correctly. When I double-click on a cell in the grid, I am able to edit and change the cell data (as have successfully been done in the react-data-grid sample code, https://adazzle.github.io/react-data-grid/docs/examples/simple-grid). However after editing and when I move to another cell, I get the error: Cannot read property 'setState' as undefined which the error message I reproduce below. How do I fix this error? Thank you in advance!

Error message:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'setState' of undefined
onGridRowsUpdated
C:/kilostep_material/kilostep/src/App.js:59

> 59 | this.setState(state => {
     | ^  60 |   const rows = state.rows.slice();
  61 |   for (let i = fromRow; i <= toRow; i++) {
  62 |     rows[i] = { ...rows[i], ...updated };
View compiled
▶ 21 stack frames were collapsed.
```

App.js

```
import React, {useState} from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import ReactDataGrid from "react-data-grid";
import axios from 'axios';





export default function App() {


  const [isLoaded, setIsLoaded] = useState(false);


  const [rows,setRows] = useState([]);




  React.useEffect(() => {
      async function anyNameFunction() {
        const response = await axios.get('http://localhost:8080/user/all');
        setIsLoaded(true);
          console.log(response.data);
          setRows(response.data);
      }

      anyNameFunction();


  }, [])



  const columns = [
    { key: "_id", name: "_id", width: 250 },
    { key: "id", name: "ID", width: 100 },
    { key: "userName", name: "User Name", width: 250, editable: true, enableCellSelect: true },
    { key: "userTelNo", name: "Tel No", width: 250, editable: true, enableCellSelect: true },
    { key: "userEmail", name: "EMail", width: 250, editable: true, enableCellSelect: true },
    { key: "userRole", name: "Role", width: 150, editable: true, enableCellSelect: true },
    { key: "dateSaved", name: "Date Saved", width: 250 },
];



const state = { rows };



const onGridRowsUpdated = ({ fromRow, toRow, updated }) => {


updated.userName);

  this.setState(state => {
    const rows = state.rows.slice();
    for (let i = fromRow; i <= toRow; i++) {
      rows[i] = { ...rows[i], ...updated };
    }
    return { rows };
  });
};



  return (
    <ReactDataGrid
      columns={columns}
      rowGetter={i => state.rows[i]}
      onGridRowsUpdated={onGridRowsUpdated}
      rowsCount={rows.length}
      minHeight={500}
      enableCellSelect={true}
    />
  );
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case, you're trying to set the `rows` in your **functional** component using the `this.setState` which can only be used in class type `Component`s. The keyword `this` is not accessible in functional components. You need to use the `setRows` from the useState hook you defined above in your code like this:

```
setRows(previousState => {
     //perform your calculation here
})
```

Comment: Thank you very much Sowmen! I have upvoted and accepted your answer!